# Start a SQL COUNT Query with a negative base value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How would I get a COUNT query to return a value only if there were more than 30 in the count?

```
SELECT
COUNT (DISTINCT a.orders)
FROM dbo.orders_table a
WHERE a.unshipped
```

If it returned 29 the count would be NULL but 30 or greater would return the integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `NULL` in a column, you would use `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT a.orders) >= 30 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT a.orders) END)
FROM dbo.orders_table a
WHERE a.unshipped ??;
```

What is the condition in the `WHERE`?

If you want *no rows*, then use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.orders)
FROM dbo.orders_table a
WHERE a.unshipped
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.orders) >= 30 ;
```

Comment: No the first one was just what I needed. Escaped me on how to do it. I'll file the second one for sure though. Thank you again.